# Trouble to read array of record from kafka topic using pyspark readstream

Tags: apache-spark, avro, spark-structured-streaming

I am using pyspark readstream from a kafka topic with an array of records like [ {}, {}, {} ].
I was able to parse a single record using from_avro( F.col('value'), avro_schema ).
However, the actual data from the topic is an array of records and I try to add [] around my avro schema but does not work.

the avro schema for single record is

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "data",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "x",
            "type": [
                "double",
                "null"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "y",
            "type": [
                "double",
                "null"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

but what I need is an avro schema that can parse an array of this record [ {}, {}]

I know I can use pandas UDF but I just want to know if there is a native way(using spark API) to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Kafka payload is an array, your Avro schema needs to start like

```
{
"type": "array",
"items": {
    "type": "record",
    "name": "data",
    "fields": [
      ...
```

You can't simply add `[]` around a record type.

Then, Spark should return an array of Struct types for the deserialized value column

Also worth mentioning - `from_avro`, by default, does not work if your Kafka data was produced using Confluent Schema Registry...

Comment: Yes, I have to delete the first 5 bytes In order to parse with AVRO. just curious why there would be such a difference between confluent Kafka and Kafka

Comment: There isn't a difference. It's Avro serialization that's different, which has nothing to do with Kafka which just stores the bytes. More specifically, you're not required to use the registry to produce Avro data into Kafka